# Can you prove the following sequent by using the natural deduction rules?

Tags: natural-deduction

(p→q)→r, s→¬p , t , (¬s∧t) → q ⊢ r
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Start with $t$ and assume either $s$ or $\neg s$.  Can both cases lead to $r$?

Comment: Yes. For that we can use LEM rule.(sV¬s)

Comment: Assume $P$, derive $Q$. Then discharge the assumption $P$ obtaining $P \implies Q$. Use modus ponens to derive $R$ from premise 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with ¬r, and find the contradiction (t∧¬t). It took me 14 steps. Maybe it is not the best way, but *reductio ad absurdum* usually works fine :)